# Where can I buy Or Hashem?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, product-recommendation, jewish-books, rishonim

I found a new printing of Or Hashem by R. Chasdai Crescas on hebrewbooks.org ([here](http://hebrewbooks.org/22063)), but I can't find it or any other print for sale. Any ideas?

Comment: See [this](http://www.amazon.fr/Lumi%C3%A8re-l%C3%A9ternel-Hasda%C3%AF-Crescas/dp/2705670394) for french speackers

Comment: I can sell you [this version](http://www.amazon.com/Sefer-Adonai-Hebrew-Crescas-Hasdai/dp/1172084556/) (a photo-offset of [the Ferrera 1555 edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/42421)) if you'd like, but you're probably better off just making a book from printing R. Fisher's edition on hebrewbooks

Comment: I have seen it at the Moznaim warehouse in Boro Park

Answer (score 1):

The Mizrahi store on Ebay has several volumes for sale, including this one http://www.ebay.com/itm/Hebrew-OHR-HASHEM-RABBI-HASDAI-CRESCAS-Makor-Reprint-1555-1st-Edition-/391641946120?hash=item5b2fadd808

Answer (score 0):

You can try to order a print version from the Hebrew Books site through [this](http://www.publishyoursefer.com/reprints/id/HB-22063) link.

There are online publishing houses that take pdf files and print them up for sale - the question here would be "who has rights to the text" because if one were to download the pdf and get it printed, the money should, I would think, go to the rights holder.

Comment: in Atar Daat you have [this](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/orhashem/orhashem02.pdf)